# How to partially read input until a new line using read()?

Tags: c, input, buffer

I'm trying to partially read input until a new line is inputed "\n". But how can I do that with the read() function? Right now I've made the partial read until the terminal interface is logged out and the input is stopped (pressing ctrl+d on linux terminal), but don't know how to make it stop when a new line is inputted. Here is my code:

```
int fd = 0;
const size_t read_size = 100;
size_t size = read_size;
char *buff = malloc(size+1);
size_t offset = 0;
size_t res = 0;

while((res = read(fd, buff + offset, read_size)) > 0)
{
    offset += res;
    buff[offset] = '\0';
    if (offset + read_size > size)
    {
        size *= 2;
        buff = realloc(buff, size+1);
    }
}
return buff;
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `fgets` function?

Comment: I'm working at an OS level, so only using read,write,open,close,lseek, etc. And its partial read because its faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to partially read input until a new line is inputed "\n". But how can I do that with the read() function?

The only way you can achieve this with a `read` is to read one character at a time. Once you've read the `'\n'` character, stop.

> how do I check what is being read?

```
while (read(fd, buf + offset, 1) == 1) {
  if (buf[offset] == '\n') break;
  offset += 1;
}
```

Comment: You can also achieve it by buffering the input, read as a block.

Comment: Okay, but how do I check what is being read?